# Perl XML findnodes Error

Tags: xml, perl, xpath

In my Perl Script I try to parse a XML File with XML::XPath.
I do the following:

```
my $xml = XML::XPath->new(filename => "dat.xml");
foreach my $row ($xml->findnodes('/pack/data')) {
...
}
```

I get an error in findnodes, but I don't now, how to find it. The scripts just prints out "Getötet". I don't use perl die function.

The xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE pack SYSTEM "qy.dtd">
<pack>

<data>
        <d0>88485488</d0>
        <d1>58915015</d1>
        <d2>56</d2>
        <d3>0</d3>
</data>

<data>
        <d0>88485511</d0>
        <d1>16023676</d1>
        <d2>56</d2>
        <d3>0</d3>

</data>
</pack>
```

How can I find the error? The XML is about 10 MB big.

Thank you !

Comment: Do you have `use strict; use warnings;` at the top of your script, and have you validated your XML against your DTD? Please post your DTD with the question as commenting out the DTD line lets the document load normally.

Comment: Yes, I have use strict; use warnings; at the beginning. When I remove the dtd line from my xml file, the same error occurs. Both are valid xml / dtd files. I can't post them here because of copyright limitations.

Comment: It's worth noting that XML::XPath is an old abandoned module.  XML::LibXML provides almost exactly the same API, uses less memory, is faster, less buggy and has more features.

Answer (score 0):

I note that ["Getötet" is German for "killed"](https://translate.google.co.uk/#auto/en/Get%C3%B6tet). It may be that the particular setup you are using is not suitable for parsing and holding in memory a 10MB input file, and this is usually needed for XPath queries to function. The diagnostic "Killed" is not very helpful, but sometimes indicates that a Unix-type operating system (e.g. Linux) has run out of available memory for the process in question, and has resorted to simply killing the process.

Here's what I'd do:

1. Strip out many of the `<data>` chunks in the file, leaving the file format the same, and rerun your program.
2. If it succeeds, it may well have been a case of the file being too big, but now you have a smaller file which works which you can test your program on.
3. Alternatively, if it *still* doesn't work keep making the file smaller until it does, or you have a *very* small file which exhibits this behaviour, and then ask again.

If it is a file size issue, one way to deal with it is to make more memory available to your program - increase the physical and/or virtual memory size, reduce other processes running at the same time. But if your data is likely to grow over the lifetime of this program, that's going to be only a temporary solution.

A more long-term way would be to rethink how you're accessing the data. There are different ways of processing XML files which *don't* need the whole file in memory at once, such as [Simple API for XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML) (SAX), although that is a *completely* different approach to working with XML, and would take quite a lot of work compared to simply using XPath. But it would continue to work on increasingly larger input files.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest `XML::Twig` instead - for two reasons. You can still `findnodes` with it if you want, and that's pretty neat.

However, it also lets you do `twig_handlers` for handling larger XML files efficiently. 10MB is unlikely to be a problem, but bear in mind the XML memory footprint can quite easily be 10x the source.

So you can:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

use XML::Twig;

#set a callback. 
sub handle_data {
    #twig is the whole thing, data is this node. 
    my ( $twig, $data ) = @_; 

    print "New data node:\n";
     #read child elements. 
    foreach my $node ( $data -> children ) { 
        #print it. 
        print $node -> tag, " = ", $node -> text, "\n";
    }
    #discard data thus far procesed. 
    $twig -> purge;
}

#instantiate the parser, configure the handler. 
my $twig = XML::Twig -> new ( twig_handlers => { '/pack/data' => \&handle_data } ) 
#parse the data FH. Can use 'parsefile' here instead. 
   $twig -> parse ( \*DATA ); 


__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE pack SYSTEM "qy.dtd">
<pack>

<data>
        <d0>88485488</d0>
        <d1>58915015</d1>
        <d2>56</d2>
        <d3>0</d3>
</data>

<data>
        <d0>88485511</d0>
        <d1>16023676</d1>
        <d2>56</d2>
        <d3>0</d3>

</data>
</pack>
```

This prints:

```
New data node:
d0 = 88485488
d1 = 58915015
d2 = 56
d3 = 0
New data node:
d0 = 88485511
d1 = 16023676
d2 = 56
d3 = 0
```

But you can still do findnodes the way you'd intended:

```
#instantiate the parser.
my $twig = XML::Twig -> new ( ); 
#parse the data FH. Can use 'parsefile' here instead. 
   $twig -> parse ( \*DATA ); 

foreach my $row ( $twig -> findnodes ( '/pack/data' ) ) { 
    $row -> print;
}
```